# How to remove duplicate ints before a certain element in Scala

Tags: list, scala, filter, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a list that can have certain numbers before an index that I don't need. For example:

```
val tempList: List[Any] = List(0,0,0,0,0,3,.,5,0,2,5)
```

How would I be able to remove all of the 0's before 3 without filtering out the 0 after the 3?

Comment: **Any** is a code smell, it would be good to re-design your problem to avoid it.

Comment: What should be the result with `List(0,1,0,3,0)` ? Is it `List(1,0,3,0)` or `List(1,3,0)` or something else?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dropWhile`. Suppose you want to remove everything before 1:

```
scala> val l = List(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
l: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)

scala> l.dropWhile(_ == 0)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 0)
```

Comment: I think this should return `List(1,2)` not `List(1,2,0)` because that task is to "remove all of the 0's before 3" and since your sample data doesn't have a 3 that means all the 0s.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is a twist on `dropWhile`, that I would call `filterWhile`.

One simple solution that leverages the Collection API is the following:

```
def filterWhile[A](
    list: List[A]
)(filterP: A => Boolean, whileP: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  val (toFilter, unfiltered) = list.span(whileP)
  toFilter.filter(filterP) ++ unfiltered
}
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/OAGZOoMfTiGftdsGKmz64A/25), alongside a couple of tests to verify it works as expected, which are the following:

```
def test[A](
    input: List[A],
    expected: List[A]
)(filterP: A => Boolean, whileP: A => Boolean): Unit =
  assert(
    filterWhile(input)(filterP, whileP) == expected,
    s"input: $input, expected: $expected, got: ${filterWhile(input)(filterP, whileP)}"
  )

test(
  input = List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, '.', 5, 0, 2, 5),
  expected = List(3, '.', 5, 0, 2, 5)
)(filterP = _ != 0, whileP = _ != 3)

test(
  input = List(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, '.', 5, 0, 2, 5),
  expected = List(1, 3, '.', 5, 0, 2, 5)
)(filterP = _ != 0, whileP = _ != 3)

test(
  input = List(1, 2, 3, 4),
  expected = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
)(filterP = _ < 5, whileP = _ < 5)
```

In your case in particular all you have to do is invoke the function as follows:

```
filterWhile(tempList)(_ != 0, _ != 3)
```

Where the first predicate says how to filter and the second defines the "while" clause. I chose to align the predicate ordering to the name of the function (it first says "filter" and then "while") but feel free to adjust according to your preference. In any case, using named parameters is probably a good thing here.

Answer (score 1):

Combining existing functions on lists, I came up with:

```
def filterUntil[A](list: List[A], filter: A => Boolean, cond: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
    list.takeWhile(cond).filter(filter) ++ list.dropWhile(cond)
}
```

This produces much the same results as @stefanobaghino's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be done with a `foldLeft` but in this case I would got for a recursive routine:

```
def remove(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  def loop(rem: List[Any], res: List[Any]): List[Any] =
    rem match {
      case Nil =>
        res
      case 0 :: tail =>
        loop(tail, res)
      case 3 :: _ =>
        res ++ rem
      case x :: tail =>
        loop(tail, res :+ x)
      }

  loop(list, Nil)
}

remove(List(0,0,0,0,0,3,".",5,0,2,5))
// List(3, ., 5, 0, 2, 5)
```

Note that this won't be efficient for long lists because adding to the tail of a `List` gets very slow with longs lists.

Also, as noted in the comments, you should avoid `Any` if possible and use a more specific type.

[ Simplifications thanks to @MikhailIonkin ]

Comment: it's too complicated. Scala was been created for write a simple code. This example invert it. Also  this code used `Any` as type of argument. Commonly it is a bad practice

Comment: @MikhailIonkin If you have a simpler solution then please post it. The answer uses `Any` because the question uses `Any`, and I explicitly say this is a bad idea in my answer.

Comment: you can simplify `(x: Int) :: tail if x == 0` to `0 :: tail`, for example. Also I think it is better to rename `remove` function and rename arguments of `loop`.